# Javascript arrays storing values

Tags: javascript, arrays

There might be a very simple solution my problem but just not being able to find one so please help me to get to my solution in the simplest way...

The issue here is that I have data being displayed in a tabular form. Each row has 5 columns and in one of the columns it shows multiple values and so that's why I need to refer to a value by something like this row[1]['value1'], row[1]['value2'] & then row[2]['value1'], row[2]['value2'].

I declare the array

```
var parray = [[],[]];
```

I want to store the values in a loop something like this

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 10; counter ++){
     parray[counter]['id'] += 1;
     parray[counter]['isavailable'] += 0;
}
```

Later I want to loop through this and get the results:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < parray.length; idx++) {
    var pt = {};
    pt.id = parray[schctr][idx].id;
    pt.isavailable = parray[schctr][idx].isavailable;
}
```

Obviously iit's not working because Counter is a numeric key and 'id' is a string key ..my question how do I achieve this ??

Thanks for all the answers in advance.

Comment: First of all you need to realize that there _is_ no such thing as “associative arrays” in JavaScript – what you _mean_ is an object.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [For each in an array. How to do that in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript) - when you add element by non-numeric index you need use `for(idx in object)` to iterate as covered in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want inside your array is just a plain object:

```
// just a regular array
var parray = [];

for(var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++){
  // create an object to store the values
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = counter;
  obj.isavailable = 0;
  // add the object to the array
  parray.push(obj);
}
```

later:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < parray.length; idx++) {
  var pt = parray[idx];
  // do something with pt
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JS has no concept of "associative arrays". You have arrays and objects (map). Arrays are objects though, and you *can* put keys, but it's not advisable.

You can start off with a blank array

```
var parray = [];
```

And "push" objects into it

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++){
  parray.push({
    id : 1,
    isAvailable : 0
  });
}
```

Then you can read from them

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < parray.length; idx++) {

  // Store the current item in a variable
  var pt = parray[idx];
  console.log(pt);

  // read just the id
  console.log(parray[idx].id);
}
```

[Like I did here](http://jsfiddle.net/7MM3a/)

Comment: The issue here is that I have data being displayed in a tabular form. Each row has 5 columns and in one of the columns it shows multiple values and so that's why I need to refer to a value by something like this row[1]['value1'], row[1]['value2'] & then row[2]['value1'], row[2]['value2'] and so in the above code if I say id:1 ...it will not know which row it belongs to when I need to get it's value ..I hope I have been able to explain :)

Comment: @user3578905 These "multiple values", do they mean something individually (like translations) or collectively (like "animals")? Are they uniform on all rows (contain 3 each) or variable? It would be better if you explain further in your post.